# How to count unique characters in a string?

Tags: vb.net

For example, for the string "I am a human", the code has to return integer 6 (spaces are not counted).

For space removal, I used:

```
line = line.Replace(" ", "")
```

Unfortunately, I'm lost on what to do after.

Comment: Shouldn't it return 6 (i.e., `{I, a, m, h, u, n}`)?

Comment: you are right Ahmed, edited.

Answer (score 3):

Since a `String` is an `IEnumerable(Of Char)`, you may use the [`Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct) LINQ method to get the unique characters and then check their `Count()`.

Try something like this:

```
Dim s As String = "I am a human"
Dim uniqueCharactersCount = s.Where(Function(c) c <> " "c).Distinct().Count()
Console.WriteLine(uniqueCharactersCount)    ' 6
```

---

If you're going to be using this a lot, you may convert it to an extension method:

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function UniqueCharsCount(s As String, 
                                 Optional excludeSpace As Boolean = True) As Integer
    Dim distinctChars = s.Distinct()
    If excludeSpace Then distinctChars = distinctChars.Where(Function(c) c <> " "c)
    Return distinctChars.Count()
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
Dim s As String = "I am a human"
Console.WriteLine(s.UniqueCharsCount())    ' 6
```

Comment: Alternative Linq: `Dim count = "I am a human".Distinct().Count(Function(c) c <> ChrW(32))`

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
Console.WriteLine(Strings.Replace("I am an alien", " ", "").ToList.Distinct.Count)
```

Comment: Bear in mind, that `Replace` creates a new string and does not modify the existing string.  Therefore, you end up with two strings in memory.  While this may not be an issue in this example, if you are working with thousands or millions of strings, this could potentially use a lot of memory.  Also `ToList` is not necessary in this code as `Replace` returns a `string` which implements `IEnumerable(Of Char)`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thank you so much for advice. I appreciate so much this. But I think you get up in OP question this comment.